# GoogleSheets Script get logged in user to hide/show columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Obviously I am clueless at scripting. Just trying to fire a manual script by the sheet's current user - obtains their Goggle User Email and then will hide or show certain columns. I am lost and have no idea what I am doing, as you can tell. Any help would be so very appreciated.
Firing script manually by logged in user via script embedded image on Sheet that is clicked after opening sheet.

```
function onChoice(e){
var email = (Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail());
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if (e.user() !== 'email') return;
switch (e.value) {
          case 'HISlegit@email.com':
            sheet.showColumns(1, sheet.getMaxColumns() - 1)
            break;
          case 'HERlegit@email.com':
            sheet.showColumns(5, 2)
                sheet.hideColumns(7, 6)
            break;
          case 'MINElegit@email.com':
            sheet.showColumns(7, 6)
            sheet.hideColumns(5, 2)
            break;
}
}
```

Comment: Just glancing at it, the source of the problem is probably around 'if (e.user() !== 'email') return;' as that doesn't appear to be formatted properly. Try removing that for a start, see if that gets you anywhere. Otherwise, I'll have a closer look when i get home and am not on my phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here's a very simple adjustment that does what you describe, but I wasn't going to mess about with the 'Clicking and image' thing, you'll have to find how it's going to work with your existing code.

The following will open/close columns based on your email [using a simple 'onOpen' trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onopen):

```
function onOpen(e){
  var email = (Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  switch (email){
      case 'HISlegit@email.com':
            sheet.showColumns(1, sheet.getMaxColumns() - 1);
            sheet.hideColumns(5, 2);
            break;  
      case 'HERlegit@email.com':
            sheet.showColumns(5, 2);
            sheet.hideColumns(7, 6);
            break;
      case 'MINElegit@email.com':
            sheet.showColumns(7, 6);
            sheet.hideColumns(5, 2);
            break;
  };
}
```

It currently works for me. The issues you were having were centered around the 'if (e.user() !== 'email') return;' as I expected, but I've not tested anything related to 'var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();' as I'm not sure what data is being passed in via 'e; (I don't believe 'onChoice' is a Google Trigger).

This should resolve the code issue you're having.